# ATOM package install fails, as well as updates

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for a while now and never had an issue. However lately when I went to install a new package (minimap) this the error I got. I also get a very similar error when update packages. I believe the issue has something to do with `https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-utils` but I don't know where to switch off the the https.

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-utils failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-utils failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
npm ERR!     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
npm ERR!     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR!   message: 'request to https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-utils failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   stack: 'FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/atom-utils failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)',
npm ERR!   parent: 'minimap' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.atom/.apm/_logs/2018-12-21T03_25_51_526Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple:

1. Disable Pi-Hole.
2. Update Atom, install new packages
3. Enable Pi-Hole